# How to make launchScreen background color changing dynamically?

Tags: xcode, swift5, appdelegate, launch-screen

#### What I have

OK, I have an App with multi Theme feature.. every time the user will chose his favorite theme... the BKG color will be stored in the userDefault

#### What I want

I want to pass this chosed color immediately to the launchScreen ((before the user close the App)) in order to be loaded in the next App launch.

1. I know that the launch screen is static and can't be changed in any way at runtime.
2. I know that the launch screen is shown before your app is actually running.
3. Also I know that we cannot add or link code to the launchScreen file because it will give the below error:

[image]

BUT!!
My idea is to change the launchScreen given color in the Assets.xcassets colors set by doing some trick by changing the actual color of the ((Assets color file)) programmatically!

Hope you got the trick ✅... I need your help on

How to change the color value in assists programmatically not manually (without changing its name).

**The question is:**
Will this method work or not?

Comment: You have an idea, did you try it? Did it work? If yes, what is the question then? If no, what exactly didn't work out and how can the community help?

Comment: First of all I didn't downvote your question, what made you think it's me? Mind your words, buddy. Second, I don't get, what's the actual question in your post. The only phrase that is a question is "Will this method is gonna work or not?". So, my question is did you try your method? If you try it, you'll now if it works.

Answer (score 1):

> How to change the color value in assists programmatically not manually (without changing its name).

An asset catalog, like all aspects of an app bundle and its contents, cannot be changed programmatically by the app.

This is for two reasons:

- There is no programming API for doing it.
- If it were somehow done, it would constitute a security violation (the app would no longer match its own checksum) and the app would refuse to launch.

The only way to run the app with a different asset catalog would be for the user to download and install a different version of the app, which has a different asset catalog.